# Change PreferenceCategory android:title

Tags: android, categories, preference

I was wondering if there was a way to change the

`PreferenceCategory android:title="my name"`

programmatically and or the

`ListPreference android:title="my name"`

programmatically.

Answer (score 19):

Keith,

Yes, there is a way to change the title programmatically. You must add a android:key="myTag" in your xml layout for the PreferenceCategory.  Then you can access the PreferenceCategory from code by using findPreference("myTag").   The code is below:

XML:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="My Preferences"
   android:key="myPreferencesTitle" 
>
```

Java code:

```
PreferenceCategory prefCat=(PreferenceCategory)findPreference("myPreferencesTitle");
prefCat.setTitle("My New Title");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I was trying to use `findViewById` and your answer was just what I was looking for :-)